# Subscript out of range error during Cartesian product

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I'm trying to find the Cartesian product of 4 columns which have data separated by delimiter

Example

```
ID                     ID2                         String           String2 
1234   33423,43222,442224,213432    Sample;repeat;example;multiple second; possible;delimiter
2345 12354; 55633; 343534;65443;121121 data;set;sample;find     answer;combination;by
```

and I get an error Subscript out of range with the below code. Can anyone help with where it is going wrong?

```
Sub Cartesian()
    Dim MyStr1 As Variant, MyStr2 As Variant, MyStr3 As Variant, MyStr4 As Variant, _
    Str1 As Variant, Str2 As Variant, Str3 As Variant, Str4 As Variant, X As Long, _
    OrigString1 As Variant, OrigString2 As Variant, OrigString3 As Variant, _
    OrigString4 As Variant, Y As Long

    OrigString1 = Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    OrigString2 = Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    OrigString3 = Range("C2:C" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    OrigString4 = Range("D2:D" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    X = 2

    For Y = LBound(OrigString1) To UBound(OrigString1)

        MyStr1 = Split(OrigString1(Y), ";")
        MyStr2 = Split(OrigString2(Y), ";")
        MyStr3 = Split(OrigString3(Y), ";")
        MyStr4 = Split(OrigString4(Y), ";")

        For Each Str1 In MyStr1
            For Each Str2 In MyStr2
                For Each Str3 In MyStr3
                    For Each Str4 In MyStr4
                        Range("A" & X).Formula = Str1
                        Range("B" & X).Formula = Str2
                        Range("C" & X).Formula = Str3
                        Range("D" & X).Formula = Str4
                        X = X + 1
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next

    Next
End Sub
```

Or is there a better way to deal with this using sql? Or any better way to achieve the Cartesian product of every row using VBA?

Comment: A *Runtime error 9: Subscript out of range* is usually pretty specific. Essentially it means that you are referencing like a worksheet that doesn't exist or you are trying to stuff more elements into an array than the array's dimensions can handle. What line are you receiving the error on?

Comment: OrigString1 = Range("A2:A" & Range("A" @Jeeped

Comment: This is weird. If you want to assign an array -which is created from a range by assigning- to another range, vba does this but can not be got an element by index from the same array. Dont use a variant array; use a string array and get the values for assigning the array by looping cells of the range. Code is seen right.

Comment: @kitap mitap can you suggest an update on the code? I'm a very beginner in VBA having tough time getting through this

Comment: I has written an answer.

Comment: I have edited ReDim statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works. I could not find a more elegant solution.

```
Sub Cartesian()
    Dim MyStr1() As String
    Dim MyStr2() As String
    Dim MyStr3() As String
    Dim MyStr4() As String
    Dim X As Long
    Dim OrigString1() As String
    Dim OrigString2() As String
    Dim OrigString3() As String
    Dim OrigString4() As String
    Dim Y As Long

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ReDim OrigString1(1 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)

    For Y = 1 To UBound(OrigString1)
        OrigString1(Y) = CStr(Range("A" & CStr(Y + 1)).Value)
    Next

    ReDim OrigString2(1 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)

    For Y = 1 To UBound(OrigString2)
        OrigString2(Y) = CStr(Range("B" & CStr(Y + 1)).Value)
    Next

    ReDim OrigString3(1 To Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)

    For Y = 1 To UBound(OrigString3)
        OrigString3(Y) = CStr(Range("C" & CStr(Y + 1)).Value)
    Next

    ReDim OrigString4(1 To Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)

    For Y = 1 To UBound(OrigString4)
        OrigString4(Y) = CStr(Range("D" & CStr(Y + 1)).Value)
    Next

    X = 2

    For Y = LBound(OrigString1) To UBound(OrigString1)

        MyStr1() = Split(OrigString1(Y), ";")
        MyStr2() = Split(OrigString2(Y), ";")
        MyStr3() = Split(OrigString3(Y), ";")
        MyStr4() = Split(OrigString4(Y), ";")

        For Each Str1 In MyStr1
            For Each Str2 In MyStr2
                For Each Str3 In MyStr3
                    For Each Str4 In MyStr4
                        Range("A" & X).Formula = Str1
                        Range("B" & X).Formula = Str2
                        Range("C" & X).Formula = Str3
                        Range("D" & X).Formula = Str4
                        X = X + 1
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The first row contains commas and not semi-colons, that is messing up the dimensionality of the vector

Comment: It returns same error even if my data has semi-colon @Jeanno

Comment: Any more suggestions? @Jeanno

Answer (score 0):

When you are stuffing a block of cells' values into a variant array it is best not to rely upon the default property being `.Value`. Explicitly state that you want the value from the cells. In fact, use `.Value2` to get the base values from the cells.

```
OrigString1 = Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
OrigString2 = Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
OrigString3 = Range("C2:C" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
OrigString4 = Range("D2:D" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
```

See [Range.Value2 Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) for more information on `.Value2`. Specific minor properties of Currency and Date value types are not important when trying to bulk process in memory; only when the raw values get passed back to the worksheet.

Comment: @Jeeped I updated my code accordingly but it still has the same error

Comment: Put this line just above the first in the set. `Debug.Print Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Address(0, 0, external:=true)`. When it crashes, go to the VBE and tap Ctrl+G to open the Immediate window and see what it says.

Comment: @Jeeped It says `[mmm.xlsm]Sheet1!A2:A3`